# Confusion in ref list function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Hi i have a doubt in my code basic question is "is it a bad practice?" basically i am reading data from reader function and inserting the values TO ALREADY EXISTING LIST (few props) my code is something like this

```
private void TGenerateDriveDetailsFromReader<T>(SqlDataReader returnData, ref List<Systems> systemList)
    {
        try
        {
            while (returnData.Read())
            {
                int MachineID = 0;
                MachineID = returnData["MachineID"] is DBNull ? 0 : (int)returnData["MachineID"];
                if (systemList.Any(x => x.ID == MachineID))
                {
                    double totalSize = returnData["Size"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(returnData["Size"]);
                    double freeSpace = returnData["FreeSpace"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(returnData["FreeSpace"]);
                    int driveType = returnData["DriveTypeID"] is DBNull ? 0 : (int)(returnData["DriveTypeID"]);
                    InsertDriveDetailsToList(totalSize, MachineID, freeSpace, driveType, ref systemList);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }




    private void InsertDriveDetailsToList(double totalSize, int machineID, double freeSpace, int driveTypeID, ref List<Systems> systemList)
    {
        switch (driveTypeID)
        {
            case 1: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveCTotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveCFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 2: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveDTotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveDFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 3: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveETotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveEFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 4: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveFTotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveCFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 5: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveGTotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveGFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 6: systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveHTotal = totalSize;
                systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault().DriveHFree = freeSpace;
                break;
        }
    }
```

So the function with case statement will execute every time with while read loop my question is since i am referring the list too with the loop will it hit the performance?Should i change the approach ? thanks

Comment: If your code works, and you are just looking for what amounts to a code review, you should probably ask this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TiesonT. i didn't debugged yet but my confusion is since i am referring a list which already being refereed once or more then once is that gonna hurt the code stability ??

Comment: Why are you using `ref` here? I see no point where you do `systemList = ...`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain as i said the list has ready some values from another reader function which i dint included in the code

Comment: That still does not explain why you used ref

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void TGenerateDriveDetailsFromReader<T>(SqlDataReader returnData, ref List<Systems> systemList)
    {
        try
        {
            while (returnData.Read())
            {
                int MachineID = 0;
                MachineID = returnData["MachineID"] is DBNull ? 0 : (int)returnData["MachineID"];
                if (systemList.Any(x => x.ID == MachineID))
                {
                    double totalSize = returnData["Size"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(returnData["Size"]);
                    double freeSpace = returnData["FreeSpace"] is DBNull ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(returnData["FreeSpace"]);
                    int driveType = returnData["DriveTypeID"] is DBNull ? 0 : (int)(returnData["DriveTypeID"]);
        Systems systems = systemList.Where(x => x.ID == machineID).FirstOrDefault();
                    InsertDriveDetailsToList(totalSize, MachineID, freeSpace, driveType, systems);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }




    private void InsertDriveDetailsToList(double totalSize, int machineID, double freeSpace, int driveTypeID, Systems systems)
    {
        switch (driveTypeID)
        {
            case 1: systems.DriveCTotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveCFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 2: systems.DriveDTotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveDFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 3: systems.DriveETotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveEFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 4: systems.DriveFTotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveCFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 5: systems.DriveGTotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveGFree = freeSpace;
                break;

            case 6: systems.DriveHTotal = totalSize;
                systems.DriveHFree = freeSpace;
                break;
        }
    }
```

You can change this.